# Proving $\frac{x+1}{x^2+1} < 2, \quad \forall x \geq 0$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

I came across this inequality and it is apparently trivial but I just cannot see why this holds. Would anyone care to give a small proof or outline of a proof?

Comment: The key word is Completing the square.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This way avoids calculation.

When $x < 1$, $\frac{x + 1}{x^2 + 1} < \frac{x + 1}{1} = x + 1 < 2$.

When $x \geq 1$, $x \leq x^2$. Thus, $\frac{x + 1 }{x^2 + 1} \leq 1$.

Comment: Can you correct your $>$s and $\ge$s?

Answer (score 1):

First, note that $x^2+1>0$ for all $x$ real since $x^2\geq 0$ for all $x$ real. Hence $$\dfrac{x+1}{x^2+1}<2 \iff x+1<2(x^2+1)=2x^2+2 \iff 2x^2-x+1>0.$$

The discriminant of this second degree polynomial is $\Delta = (-1)^2-3(2)(1)=-5<0$. This means that $y=2x^2-x+1$ is a parabola that doesn’t intersect the $X$-axis, so its always positive or negative. Since at $x=1$ we have that $y(1)=2-1+1=2>0$ then $2x^2-x+1>0$ holds for all real numbers $x$, and in particular for $x\geq 0$.

Answer (score 0):

For all $x\ge 0$, we clearly have $2x^2-x+1=2(x-\frac14)^2+\frac78>0$. Thus, $2x^2+2=2(x^2+1)>x+1$, or $2>\frac{x+1}{x^2+1}$.

In fact, the inequality and the proof hold for all $x$.

Answer (score 0):

Multiplying both sides by $x^{2} + 1$:

$x+1<2x^2 + 2$

$2x^{2} - x + 1 > 0$

We note that $2x^{2} - x + 1 = 0 $ has no real roots since the discriminant is $-7$. Thus, since the parabola opens upwards inequality must hold. $\blacksquare$

Comment: You should probably mention why multiplying both sides by $x^2+1$ preserves the inequality.

Answer (score 0):

As for real $x,$ $x^2+1\ge1>0,$

The condition will hold true

$$\iff x+1<2(x^2+1)$$

$$\iff8(2x^2-x+1)>0$$

$$\iff(4x-1)^2+7>0$$

And $(4x-1)^2\ge0$ for real $x$

Answer (score 0):

Since $x^2+1>0$ then $$\frac{x+1}{x^2+1}<2 \Longleftrightarrow x+1<2x^2+2 \Longleftrightarrow 0<2x^2-x+1.$$
Since $\Delta = (-1)^2-4(2)(1)=-7<0$ and $2\cdot0^2-0+1=1>0$ then the inequality holds for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ (in particular for $x \geq 0$).